# Conditionally Set Entire Row to NaN/None in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame indexed by date. I would like to be able to Null out all rows where the index is greater than some value (like today) but keep them in the DataFrame. What's the best way to do this? For instance this

```
10/20/16  15, 20
10/25/16  13, 12
10/30/16  16, 15

#--> 10/30/16 should go to NaN, NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), for `mask` is necessary same `index` as `df`:

```
#convert index to datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

mask = pd.Series(df.index > pd.datetime.today(), index=df.index)
print (mask)
Date
2016-10-20    False
2016-10-25    False
2016-10-30     True
dtype: bool

df = df.mask(mask)
print (df)
               a     b
Date                  
2016-10-20  15.0  20.0
2016-10-25  13.0  12.0
2016-10-30   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df.loc[df.index > pd.datetime.today()] = np.nan
df
```

[image]